# Can't Login Because Cookie Won't Set in PHP Script

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I am trying to fix a .php script.  It is tied in to a vBulletin forum, using the vBulletin database.  However, the script has separate options from vBulletin, and is simply designed to let certain users from the forum login without having to use a separate login.  The login itself works on the script.  After enterting the user name and password, I am able to see the logged in options for a second.  However, it right away bounces me right back to the login screen.  So something isn't working correctly with the login process.  I do know that it is correctly connecting to the vBulletin database, because it tells me if I enter an invalid username or password.  So, the problem must be with setting the cookie.  Is there a certain code I could enter for setting a cookie?

Comment: without seeing the code its impossible to answer such a question

Comment: Are you getting a "Headers already sent" notice in the server error log? Fix that problem.